# C# - WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile not working (timeout)

Tags: ftp, download

Good afternoon everyone.

I'm trying to download a few files from a FTP server and I don't know why this isn't working, because the same code worked before. Now when i run the service I get the following error:

> Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion

I've tried doing other **Methods** like **GetFileSize** or even the **DeleteFile** that it's suppose to execute after the **DownloadFile** and they work, but this one isn't and i can't figure out why. Any ideas? My code is below, many thanks!

```
            FtpWebRequest reqFTP;

            reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(server + file));
            reqFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);

            reqFTP.KeepAlive = true;
            reqFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
            reqFTP.UseBinary = true;
            reqFTP.Proxy = null;
            reqFTP.UsePassive = false;
            reqFTP.Timeout = -1;

            FtpWebResponse response2 = (FtpWebResponse)reqFTP.GetResponse();
            Stream responseStream2 = response2.GetResponseStream();

            FileStream writeStream = new FileStream(folder + file, FileMode.Create);

            int Length = 2048;
            Byte[] buffer = new Byte[Length];
            int bytesRead = responseStream2.Read(buffer, 0, Length);

            while (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                writeStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                bytesRead = responseStream2.Read(buffer, 0, Length);
            }
            writeStream.Close();
            response2.Close();

            try
            {
                string uri2 = server + file;
                Uri serverUri2 = new Uri(uri);
                if (serverUri2.Scheme != Uri.UriSchemeFtp)
                {
                    return;
                }
                FtpWebRequest reqFTP2;
                reqFTP2 = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(server + file));
                reqFTP2.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
                reqFTP2.KeepAlive = false;
                reqFTP2.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DeleteFile;
                reqFTP2.UseBinary = true;
                reqFTP2.Proxy = null;
                reqFTP2.UsePassive = false;
                FtpWebResponse response3 = (FtpWebResponse)reqFTP2.GetResponse();
                Stream responseStream3 = response3.GetResponseStream();
                response3.Close();
            }
```

Comment: Problem solved...

            reqFTP.UsePassive = True;